# Best way to declare additional data and modules in a Django project

Tags: python, django, configuration, configuration-files, django-settings

## Issue #1

I'm looking for the best practice in order to declare the additional data in a Django project. Imagine I need to store a huge list of choices to use in `app1/models.py` (I have seen a lot of best practices keep declaring those choices in the body of the models). In another scenario, Imagine I need to keep tens of config data in order to use them in my `views.py`. Is it common to declare them in the function/class?

In my opinion, there would be two common methods in order to do that. (Not sure even recommended at all)

#### Method #1

I can actually keep them all in my `settings.py` file and access them with importing (like `from django.conf import settings`).

`settings.py`:

```py
...

NBA_TEAMS = (
    ("red", "Bulls"),
    ("yellow", "Lakers"),
    ...
)
```

#### Method #2

Keep them all in a file named `data.py` right next to the `settings.py`, and try importing it at the end of the settings file like this.

`settings.py`

```py
...

try:
    from .data import NBA_TEAMS, ..
except:
    pass
```

## Issue #2

Is there any best practice for creating modules in a Django project? Imagine I need to create a data validator function that receives string data from a form submission in `views.py`. Where should I keep those kinds of functions/validators/generators?

`views.py`

```py
from --- import validateUsername

def submission(request):
    ...
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if validateUsername(form.cleaned_data['username']):
        ...
```

Is there any best practice for these issues? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As per my suggestions for both your issues you should create one `constants.py` and one `utils.py` file.

Now depends on your use case if you want to use the same constants in multiple apps within your project then define it at the root next to `manage.py` or if the constants are specific to app then create it under the specific app folder next to `views.py` file.

Same for `utils.py` you should define all the utility functions / methods in one utils.py file and use it in all the apps within your project.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any official reference announcing this solution?